# Does javascript closure create a new reserved space in memory for each iteration?

Tags: javascript, closures

Im having this `closure` Code :

```
    for (var i = 0, link; i < 5; i++)
    {
        link = document.createElement("a");

        link.onclick = aaa(i);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }

    function aaa(num)
            {
                return function ()
                {
                    alert(num);
                };
            } ;
```

Ive been reading **a lot** about closure lately.

There is ONE thing which I dont understand.

- When i==0 , it comes to aaa with i=0 and being executed which  return new function which should **lock** the value `0`.

its fine.( I  understand this so far).

But what happens  the i==1 ?

- It comes again to the **SAME aaa** and now it should lock the `1` value. ok

But Wait ! it already saves the "closure" for the "0" value !

Does this structure(closure) is creating a new space in memory for each iteration ?

and if so  - how can it be ? we have only one   centralized `aaa` func !

Comment: Basically, the same goes for `link` - you're creating multiple elements of which the create code is only apparent once in the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `aaa` function is like a function factory; each call returns a **new** function (not the same) which has its `num` variable in its execution context set to the initial argument to `aaa`.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `aaa` it creates a `new` function with totally different context/scope, even you use the same arguments. The **closure** does use a space of memory to keep the context values.

Answer (score 0):

One more word I want to add to this and similar questions: in each call of the *outer* function (`aaa` in this case), there is a different local variable `num` created, which holds the value passed from `i`. It's the different versions of the variable `num` that get remember by each *inner* function instance (the anonymous function in this case), created in each `aaa(i)` call.

If the parameter from function call of the outer function (`aaa(i)` in this case) is not **passing by value** but **passing by reference**, then different versions of the local `num` may point to the same object.